# has_many :through throws "RuntimeError: Unknown bind columns. We can account for this."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, activerecord

I'm attempting to set up a many-to-many association between a `categories` table and various domain models (such as `products` and `articles`) in Rails 4.0.1, by using a `:through => :categorizations` model to capture the relationships, based on [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many) and [the guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association), but I've gone wrong somewhere.  The error message I'm getting -- `Unknown bind columns. We can account for this.` -- doesn't seem especially useful to me.  I'm not sure where to go next.

```rb
class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "#{Rails.env}_sqlserver_api"

  self.primary_key = 'id'

  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :article
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "#{Rails.env}_sqlserver_api"

  self.primary_key = 'id'

  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "#{Rails.env}_sqlserver_api"

  self.primary_key = 'id'

  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :articles, :through => :categorizations
end

class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    @articles = Article.limit(params[:limit]).offset(params[:offset])
    respond_with @articles, each_serializer: ArticleSerializer
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    respond_with @article, serializer: ArticleSerializer
  end
end
```

The `categorizations` table looks like this...

`id | category_id | category_name | categorized_type | categorized_id | created_at`

I'm still quite new to Rails, so I feel like there's a good chance I'm missing something obvious, here, so I thought I would reach out to the community.

Comment: Why do you call `establish_connection` on each model?

Comment: And why do you call `self.primary_key = 'id'` on each model? Both of these things are default behaviour.

Comment: Can you show the stacktrace that belongs to the error message?

Comment: What are your columns in categorizations?

Comment: @Arjan, I'm calling `establish_connection` because we have multiple database servers holding several legacy tables, and I'm honestly not sure why I have to call `self.primary_key = 'id'`, since as far as I understand, that _is_ the default behavior, but these models do not work without explicitly specifying it.  I would love to understand why, though.

Comment: @StavrosSouvatzis, I've updated the question to include the `categorizations` table structure.

Comment: You should have product_id, article_id in categorizations which you don't, hence the error. Rails looks for these fields for the relation. If you don't have them, how can you relate the row to your foreign data??? It's the only way to do it with the relation types (:belongs_to and :has_many) you've specified.

Comment: Ah, right you are, @StavrosSouvatzis.  I did have those columns at one point, but I keep getting myself all turned around.  I would like to use `categorized_id` to hold the foreign key and `categorized_type` to hold the table name, so I don't have to keep adding columns explicitly for anything that is categorizable.

Comment: Then you are in for some serious hacking... You need to specify the foreign_key column and the class, and I guess you could use some lambda to add the condition for the table name. Not quite sure how to do it, but it should look something like this: belongs_to :product, :class_name => "Product", :foreign_key => :categorization_id, if: lambda { categorized_type == "product"} ... again, it's a guideline, not too sure it will work

Comment: Oh, no.  I was afraid you were going so say something like that.  So, what's `:polymorphic => true` for, then?

Comment: oops... got me there... never used it

Comment: You can use a polymorphic association for what you want to do. I'll put it in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the `categorized_type` and `categorized_id` columns to set-up your polymorphic association, you have to do the following:

```
class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "#{Rails.env}_sqlserver_api"

  self.primary_key = 'id'

  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :categorized, :polymorphic => true
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "#{Rails.env}_sqlserver_api"

  self.primary_key = 'id'

  has_many :categorizations, :as => :categorized
  has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "#{Rails.env}_sqlserver_api"

  self.primary_key = 'id'

  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :articles, :through => :categorizations, :source => :categorized, :source_type => 'Article'
end
```

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html for more information.